# takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to fix this man

```
class Employee:
    location = "Riverside, CA"
    def __init__(self, name, email, role):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.role = role
    def get_info(self):
        print("Name: {0}, Email: {1}, Role: {2}".format(self.name, self.email, self.role))

class Developer(Employee):
    def init(self, name, email, role, language):
        super().__init__(name, email, role)
        self.language = language
    def get_info(self):
        print("Name: {0}, Email: {1}, Role: {2}".format(self.name, self.email, self.role))

employee_1 = Developer("Mickey Mouse", "mmouse@disney.com", "Lead Character", "Python")
employee_2 = Developer("Donald Duck", "dduck@disney.com", "Bad character", "FORTRAN")
```

I'm fairly new to coding so I'm kind of stuck rn

Answer (score 1):

Just needs a fresh set of eyes :)

Your mistake is here:

```py
class Developer(Employee):
    def init(self, name, email, role, language):
        super().__init__(name, email, role)
        self.language = language
```

It should be `__init__` not `init`. Once I make this change the code works.